# AttributeError at /cars/add_car 'int' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django

I want to add a Car to my database by using html inputs instead of forms. But when I run the code I get this  error. I am new to django so  I couldn't understand the similar problems that people had.

> AttributeError at /cars/add_car 'int' object has no attribute 'get'

**My full Traceback output**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/cars/add_car

Django Version: 3.1.7
Python Version: 3.9.0
Installed Applications:
['cars.apps.CarsConfig',
 'pages.apps.PagesConfig',
 'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
 'contact.apps.ContactConfig',
 'houses.apps.HousesConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'ckeditor',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'django.contrib.sites']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gx760_000\Desktop\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\gx760_000\Desktop\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 116, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "C:\Users\gx760_000\Desktop\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py", line 26, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /cars/add_car
Exception Value: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'
```

**My views.py**

```
def add_car(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_id = request.POST['user_id']
        brand = request.POST['brand']
        status_of_car = request.POST['status_of_car']
        city = request.POST['city']
        ilce = request.POST['ilce']
        e_mail = request.POST['e_mail']
        phone_number = request.POST['phone_number']
        car_title = request.POST['car_title']
        description = request.POST['description']
        price = request.POST['price']
        serial = request.POST['serial']
        color = request.POST['color']
        model = request.POST['model']
        year = request.POST['year']
        condition = request.POST['condition']
        body_style = request.POST['body_style']
        engine = request.POST['engine']
        transmission = request.POST['transmission']
        interior = request.POST['interior']
        kilometers = request.POST['kilometers']
        passengers = request.POST['passengers']
        power_of_engine = request.POST['power_of_engine']
        fuel_type = request.POST['fuel_type']
        no_of_owners = request.POST['no_of_owners']

        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            user_id = request.user.id
            return user_id

        car_model = Car(user_id=user_id,
                        brand=brand,
                        status_of_car=status_of_car,
                        city=city,
                        ilce=ilce,
                        e_mail=e_mail,
                        phone_number=phone_number,
                        car_title=car_title,
                        description=description,
                        price=price,
                        serial=serial,
                        color=color,
                        model=model,
                        year=year,
                        condition=condition,
                        body_style=body_style,
                        engine=engine,
                        transmission=transmission,
                        interior=interior,
                        kilometers=kilometers,
                        passengers=passengers,
                        power_of_engine=power_of_engine,
                        fuel_type=fuel_type,
                        no_of_owners=no_of_owners)

        car_model.save()
        return HttpResponse('cars')
    return render(request, 'cars/add_car.html')
```

**My template**

```
<form action="{% url 'add_car' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{user.id}}">
    {% else %}
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="0">
    {% endif %}
    <div class="featured-car content-area1">
        <div class="contact-section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-section" style="height:600px; margin-bottom:0; padding: 20px 50px 0 50px;">
                            <h3>İlan Genel Bilgi</h3>
                            <div class="form-group form-box">
                                <input type="text" name="brand" class="form-control" placeholder="Marka" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group form-box">
                                <select id="status_of_car" name="status_of_car" class="form-control" required>
                                    <option>Kiralık</option>
                                    <option>Satılık</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <h3>Konum Bilgileri</h3>
                            <div class="form-group form-box">
                                <select id="city" name="city" class="form-control" required>
                                    <option>opt1</option>
                                    (...)
                                    <option>opt2</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group form-box">
                                <input type="text" name="ilce" class="form-control" placeholder="İlçe" required>
                            </div>
                            <h3>İletişim Bilgileri</h3>
                            <div class="form-group form-box">
                                <input type="text" name="e_mail" class="form-control" placeholder="E-Posta"
                                       {% if user.is_authenticated %} value="{{user.email}}" {% endif %} required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group form-box">
                                <input type="text" name="phone_number" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefon No."
                                       {% if user.is_authenticated %} value="{{user.phone}}" {% endif %} required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="featured-car content-area1">
        <div class="contact-section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-section" style="margin-top:0; max-width:900px; height:1100px;">
                            <h3>İlan Detayları</h3>
                            <div class="form-group form-box">
                                <input type="text" name="car_title" class="form-control" placeholder="Başlık" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group form-box">
                                <script src="{% static 'ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js' %}"></script>
                                <textarea class="ckeditor" cols="80" id="description" name="description" rows="20"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div style="max-width:900px;">
                                <div class="form-group form-box" style="max-width:400px; margin-right:35px;">
                                    <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" placeholder="Fiyat (TL)" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group form-box" style="max-width:400px;">
                                    <input type="text" name="serial" class="form-control" placeholder="Seri" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div style="max-width:900px;">
                                <div class="form-group form-box" style="max-width:400px; margin-right:35px;">
                                    <input type="text" name="color" class="form-control" placeholder="Renk" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group form-box" style="max-width:400px;">
                                    <input type="text" name="model" class="form-control" placeholder="Model" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div style="max-width:900px;">
                                <div class="form-group form-box"
                                     style="max-width:400px; max-height:100px; margin-right:35px;">
                                    <select id="year" name="year" class="form-control" required>
                                        <option>>1950</option>
                                       (...)
                                        <option>2021</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group form-box" style="max-width:400px;">
                                    <input type="text" name="condition" class="form-control" placeholder="Durum" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div style="max-width:900px;">
                                <div class="form-group form-box"
                                     style="max-width:400px; max-height:100px; margin-right:35px;">
                                    <input type="text" name="body_style" class="form-control" placeholder="Gövde Tipi" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group form-box" style="max-width:400px;">
                                    <input type="text" name="engine" class="form-control" placeholder="Motor" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div style="max-width:900px;">
                                <div class="form-group form-box"
                                     style="max-width:400px; max-height:100px; margin-right:35px;">
                                    <input type="text" name="transmission" class="form-control" placeholder="Vites Tipi" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group form-box" style="max-width:400px;">
                                    <input type="text" name="interior" class="form-control" placeholder="İç Rengi" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div style="max-width:900px;">
                                <div class="form-group form-box"
                                     style="max-width:400px; max-height:100px; margin-right:35px;">
                                    <input type="text" name="kilometers" class="form-control" placeholder="Kilometre" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group form-box" style="max-width:400px;">
                                    <input type="text" name="passengers" class="form-control" placeholder="Yolcu Sayısı" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div style="max-width:900px;">
                                <div class="form-group form-box"
                                     style="max-width:400px; max-height:100px; margin-right:35px;">
                                    <input type="text" name="power_of_engine" class="form-control" placeholder="Motor Gücü" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group form-box" style="max-width:400px;">
                                    <input type="text" name="fuel_type" class="form-control" placeholder="Yakıt Tipi" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group form-box"
                                 style="max-width:400px; max-height:100px; margin-right:35px;">
                                <input type="text" name="no_of_owners" class="form-control" placeholder="El Değişim Sayısı" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="featured-car content-area1">
        <div class="contact-section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="form-section" style="margin-top:0; max-width:600px; height:900px;">
                            <h3>Fotoğraflar</h3>
                            <div class="form-group form-box"
                                 style="max-width:500px; max-height:100px; margin-right:35px; margin-left:20px;">
                                <input type="file" name="car_photo" class="form-control" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mb-0 clearfix"
                                 style="padding: 0 0 0 375px; padding: 15px 50px 0 50px; ">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn-md btn-theme float-left">Ekle</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: `return user_id` makes no sense, you should always return a HTTP response.

Answer (score 1):

In your view, we see:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    user_id = request.user.id
    return user_id
```

But it makes no sense to return the `id` of the user: a view should always return a HTTP response. You can for example return a `JsonResponse` with that id, like:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

# …

if request.user.is_authenticated:
    user_id = request.user.id
    return JsonResponse({'user_id': user_id})
```

or you might simply make other calculations with the `user_id`, so:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    user_id = request.user.id
# …
```

or something else, but it should always be a HTTP response.

Answer (score 0):

you can just get rid of all of this:

```
 if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user_id = request.user.id
        return user_id
```

and just replace it with:

```
user_id = request.user.id
```